State management with react-router
I am having a basic react app like
App.js - 
const [mode, setMode] = useState("Light");
const setMode = () => {
    /*
        ....
    */
}
const handleFire = () => {
    /*
        ....
    */
}

return(
    <>
        <Navbar mode={mode} handleFire={handleFire}/> //Common element
        <Home mode={mode}/> //For route 1
        <About mode={mode}/> //For route 2
    </>
);

Following the tutorial on react-router website, I wish to implement react-router with the following app architecture (which of course, breaks):-
App.js -
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Root/>,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/home",
          element: <Home mode={mode}/>
        },
        {
          path: "/about",
          element: <About mode={mode}/>
        }
      ]
    }    
]);
return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
);

Root.js -
return(
    <>
        <Navbar mode={mode} handleFire={handleFire}/>
        <Outlet>
    </>
);

The major issue I am facing is handling the state mode across these files. In the present scenario, if I declare and setup the state logic in App.js, then I will get error that the state if not defined for Root.js and vice-versa.
Perhaps I need to figure out a better approach to design the app and work upon the state management. How can I refactor my app to make it less complicated and make the routing work as intended?

Where exactly is the mode state not defined? It looks like it's defined in App.js... what exactly is the issue or problem? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a complete [mcve] of your code. Is there a reason you can't just pass mode down as props to Root like you do the other route components?

You could handle the state for mode in App and pass it down through context.
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
export const ModeContext = createContext();
function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');
  return (
    <ModeContext.Provider value={{mode, setMode}}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

Then, any component can get (or set) the value.
import { ModeContext } from './App';
import { useContext } from 'react';
function Home() {
    const { mode } = useContext(ModeContext);
    return 'Home content...';
}

